# BOOT_COMPLETED Receiver works on hard power down/power up, but not simple restart

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, restart

After a weird issue, I finally got my BootReceiver receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED signal from Android, kind of. It only works for hard power off/power on boots, it doesn't detect restarts from devices like HTC. I have implemented QUICKBOOT intent-filters in my Receivers, but still no luck.

My manifest contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

....

```
<receiver android:name="com.smashingboxes.speed.BootReceiver"
          android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.smashingboxes.speed.ShutdownReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I do not detect Shutdown or Boot if I do a HTC restart. Any ideas why it only seems to be working on hard shutdown/boots?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, those aren't the right "quickboot" actions. There are no actions with the names you have specified in the Android source code.

Try `com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` and `com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF`.

Comment: *Palm to forehead* That fixed my problem in detecting shutdown, still no luck on the power up though. I feel as though there might be a restart permission I am missing from HTC, but can't seem to find anything on it. Any ideas?

Comment: @zgc7009: That I can't answer. I haven't fussed with these HTC broadcasts personally, though I remembered that they were in the `com.htc` package, which is why I chimed in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, feel free to move in next door anytime. Pretty sure you have answered over half of the Android questions I have asked.